# Unable to see "Create Activity" part while creating Android application in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the thing which I am facing when trying to create a new Android application and I have checked the checkboxes for the "Create custom launcher" icon and the "Create Activity" boxes.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not done loading the Android SDK yet. Try restarting and waiting for the SDK to load.

Comment: How about try restarting your PC?

Comment: Actually just after restarting my system, I opened eclipse and met with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try updating.

"Help" -> "Install new software", then put url https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Everything is up to date

Comment: Try restarting eclipse.

Comment: yes.Iam able to open old projects and run but when iam trying to open sdk manager from eclipse, its not coming up

Comment: And iam even unable to open avd manager too. Till now i was running programs on a external device

Comment: I suggest you start fresh with a clean Eclipse install.

Comment: This is the 2nd time i am facing this problem :(

Comment: Maybe you should start using Android Studio.